# if condition using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, if-statement, user-data

I am new in codeigniter. I have problem with `if` statement when I fetch the data from database it does not show the wanted results and I have table name 'users' and in users table one column is rights. I want that when user in login which rights has '1' they show admin authority while normal user login they show normal user. also I am using sessions.
sorry for advance I am new in English.
 My code is

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('rights')==1)
```

Comment: Post the rest of your code. And please read *How to Format* section when you post a question.

Comment: if condition is not different at CI.They r same as PHP.

Comment: kindly share your rest code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
if($session_data['rights']==1)
{
 //do something
}
}
```

Comment: @AbdulMunemkhetran- :-)